# Add class to shortest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some JQuery that finds the height of the tallest element and adds that height to elements that are shorter. I need to add the class, main-nav-special-padding to the elements that are shorter using my existing Jquery. I took a stab but it didn't work. Any help is much appreciated. Here's what I have:
HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxHeight = -1;
  var element = $('.navbar-nav li a');

  element.each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {
      element.addClass('main-nav-special-padding');
    }
  });

  element.each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
.main-nav-special-padding {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
}

a.nav-button:link {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  padding: .5rem 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .3s;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}

a.nav-button:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .3s;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}

a.nav-button:hover {
  color: #2fa4e7;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #2fa4e7;
  margin: 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: transform .3s;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}

a.nav-button:active {
  color: #0f395a;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform .3s;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li><a href='Pending_Applications.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toPendingApps">Pending
                            Applications</a></li>
  <li><a href='Pending_Contracts.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toPendingContracts">Pending
                            Contracts</a> </li>
  <li><a href='Completed_Loans.aspx' class="nav-button-at" id="toCompletedLoans">Completed
                            Loans</a> </li>
  <li><a href='Dealer_Listing.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toDealerListing">Dealer Listing</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='Corporate_Account_Profiles.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toCorporateAccounts">
                            Corporate
                            Accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href='Sales_Activity.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toSalesAcivity">Activity</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='Historical_Sales.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toHistoricalSales">History</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='Sales_Staff_Promotions.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toSalesPromotions">
                            Promotions</a> </li>
  <li><a href='Sales_Staff_Profile.aspx' class="nav-button" id="toSalesProfile">My Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use css flex and not have to deal with this at all

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Hard to explain but you can look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code over and got this (after changing the background colour):

[image: Before]

I'm not sure what you mean by calculating the height as the height looks the same for every element. In case you mean the width you can add this css:

```
.navbar-nav{
    width: 200px;
}
.nav-button{
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Which gives you a 200px wide `<ul>` and each `<li>` will fill the width. It also takes of the Bullets on the `<li>` items.  If you want the elements to line up to the left instead of center just do this:

```
a.nav-button:link, 
a.nav-button:visited, 
a.nav-button:hover, 
a.nav-button:active {
         text-align: center;   
}
```

[image: After]

I'm not sure if this is solving your problem or not.  I'm just confused by which 'height' you're trying to solve for.  @huangism is correct that using flexbox would make much of your CSS unnecessary. But that's a topic for another time. Good luck!

Comment: My problem is when the viewport width shrinks, the text wraps (which is fine) so the links with two lines appear vertically aligned to middle but the links with one line of text are do not appear vertically aligned to middle.

Comment: Ah, I see.  For the text align issue make sure the property `text-align: center;` on all of the `<li>` items. Unless you want it aligned to the left.  Is this the height difference you were talking about? When you have a wrapped text element?  You could set a breakpoint so when your screen gets really small it sets the height of the <li> items to the right size. `@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    a.nav-button {
        height: 58px;
    }
}` doing it in Jquery sounds messy.  Also, not to be a stick in the mud, but why do you have such long menu item names? Can they just be 1 line?

Answer (score 0):

about this :

```
element.each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {
        element.addClass('main-nav-special-padding');
    }
});
```

`maxHeight` always  `>= $(this).height()`. so element don't add class .
you can edit same as:

```
  element.each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
  });

  element.each(function() {
    if (maxHeight > $(this).height()) {
      element.addClass('main-nav-special-padding');
    }
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
  });
```

add class to shorter elements.